# SQL Divide Multiply Execution Order

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select 3900.0 * 30097 / 30097 as result1
select 3900.0 / 30097 * 30097 as result2
```

Looking at these 2 queries would lead most people (or perhaps just me) to determine that the result would be the same (3900) however it would seem like SQL Server disagrees - waddup?

Spent an afternoon looking for a bug only to find that my issue can be resolved if I change the order of a multiply and divide - aren't we always told order doesn't matter?  Clearly SQL is rounding the result of the first operation in query 2 i.e. 3900.0 / 30097 but why?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding brackets around operators,so order won't be of any issue

```
select (3900.0 * 30097) / 30097 as result1
select 3900.0 / (30097 * 30097)as result2
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that SQL server is going to not lose decimal precision.  Arithmetic operators work left to right, and in the first equation the initial operation does not create an actual decimal component (117378300.0), while the second generates a number with six decimal digits (0.1295810).  So, in the subsequent operation, SQL Server will maintain 0 and 6 decimal places, respectively, so as not to 'lose data'.  You can actually see the difference writing the initial result to a table and observing the data types that are generated:

```
select 3900.0 * 30097 val
into tbl_a

select 3900.0 / 30097  val
into tbl_b

select table_name, column_name, numeric_precision, numeric_scale
from information_schema.columns 
where  table_name in ( 'tbl_a', 'tbl_b')
```

generates:

```
table_name  column_name numeric_precision   numeric_scale
tbl_a   val 11  1
tbl_b   val 11  7 <-- decimal component
```

Answer (score 0):

Exactly what You need - is next query

```
select result1 = convert(float,3900.0) * 30097 / 30097  

select convert(float,3900.0)/ 30097 * 30097enter as result2
```

i.e. You have to convert one number explicitly to float. That's all